# Promise.all return [null, null] and not return as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, feathersjs

I have written a `promise.all` function as follow which is not returning my expected result.

```
if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return Promise.all(data.map((data) => {
        hook.app.service('location')
        .find({ query: { serviceLocationId:"100" } })
        .then((result) => {
            var startDept = result.data[0];
            if (result.data.length > 0) {
                data.problem.solutions.solution.routes.route.forEach((d) => {
                    d.stops.unshift({
                        serviceType: '',
                        orders: [],
                        travelTime:'',
                        travelDistance:'',
                        travelCost:'',
                        serviceTime: '',
                        serviceTimeCost:0,
                        tripNumber:0,
                        stopName : startDept.description,
                        arrivalTime:'',
                        departureTime : 36000.0,
                        locationType : startDept.locationType,
                        sequence : 0,
                        locationId : startDept.serviceLocationId,
                        lng : startDept.location.lng,
                        lat : startDept.location.lat
                    });
                    var endDept = d.stops.pop();
                    d.stops.push({
                        serviceType: '',
                        orders: [],
                        travelTime:endDept.travelTime,
                        travelDistance:endDept.travelDistance,
                        travelCost:endDept.travelCost,
                        serviceTime: '',
                        serviceTimeCost:0,
                        tripNumber:0,
                        stopName : startDept.description,
                        arrivalTime : endDept.arrivalTime,
                        departureTime:'',
                        locationType : startDept.locationType,
                        sequence : endDept.sequence,
                        locationId : endDept.locationId,
                        lng : startDept.location.lng,
                        lat : startDept.location.lat
                    });
                });
                hook.data = data;
                combineArr = [];
                return routes(hook).then((hook) => {
                    if ([hook.data].length > 0) {
                        combineArr.push(hook.data);
                        return combineArr;
                    } else {
                        next(new Error('routes response create failed'));
                    }
                }).catch((err) => { return next(new Error(err.error)); });
            } else {
                next(new Error('no depo found'));
            }
        }).catch(err=>{ return next(new Error(err.error)); });
    })).then((results) => {
        console.log(results);
        hook.result = results;
        next();
    });
}
```

The promise above returns **`[null, null]`**. I'm not getting the expected result. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Please have a read through [mcve]. If you do what it describes, it helps you diagnose and correct problems like this (or if you still can't figure it out, it gives you a nice, contained example to use when asking others for help).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the `map` callback, so the resulting array is an array of `undefined`, not promises. You need to *return* the promise you're getting in the callback so the array is an array of promises.

Basically, you're doing this:

```
return Promise.all(myArray.map(entry => {
    getAPromise(entry);
}));
```

...where you should be doing

```
return Promise.all(myArray.map(entry => {
    return getAPromise(entry);
}));
```

....or

```
return Promise.all(myArray.map(entry => getAPromise(entry)));
```

Comment: how to do in my code above, please mention the same.@T.J.Crowder

Comment: @KARTHIKEYAN.A: Again: Return the promise out of the callback.